# FormsAuthentication with enabled slidingExpiration is not returning a cookie in each request.

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, httpcookie

I have a web application with FormsAuthentication and with `slidingExpiration="true"` in my web.config is not returning a cookie in each request, but when I see the HTTP transactions, I cannot see the webserver returning the AUTH cookie in each request.

Checking the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx), it should.

> slidingExpiration Optional attribute. Specifies whether sliding
>   expiration is enabled. Sliding expiration resets the active
>   authentication time for a cookie to expire upon each request during a
>   single session. This attribute can be one of the following values.
>   Value Description True    Specifies that sliding expiration is enabled.
>   The authentication cookie is refreshed and the time to expiration is
>   reset on subsequent requests during a single session. False   Specifies
>   that sliding expiration is not enabled and the cookie expires at a set
>   interval from the time the cookie was originally issued.  The default
>   is True.

Does anyone know why it is not working as expected?

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have read this: http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/asp-net-security/2316/problem-with-slidingExpiration

> In other words, if the elapsed time since ticket creation is greater
>   then  half the ticket timeout (in your scenario would be 1 minute) the
>   the ticket  won't be renewed. Otherwise a new ticket will be granted
>   with a fresh  timeout (2 mins in your case). Summarizing, if you hit
>   your page after 1 minute, it won't extend your Forms  session lifetime
>   regardless your slidingExpiration setting.

It makes sense, but I cannot find any official source. So I will test it my self when I have some spare time.

Cheers.

Comment: Couldn't answer fastest enough, the algorithm mentioned above can be flawed depending on your requirements.

Comment: Answer it and I am happy to mark your answer as correct :) Why could it be flawed? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.slidingexpiration.aspx

Answer (score 0):

New Cookies will issue only when half of the time is elapsed from cookies creation and that is happening in your case.